# How to calculate if there is intersection between 2 ranges of ints in Java

Tags: java, intersection

I have 2 maximum and minimum values, for example:

```
22 ------ 26 and 16 ------ 22 (OK, because of 22)
22 ------ 26 and 10 ------ 12 (FAILS)
22 ------ 30 and 29 ------ 33 (OK because of 29 and 30)
```

I want to know if there exists an intersection between the sets that represent the maximum and minimum, in Java.

I've tried to do it in a paper and got an if with 4 tests, but I found they fail:

```
if ((thisEntityLeftPosX <= anotherEntityLeftPosX && thisEntityRightPosX >= anotherEntityRightPosX)
            || (thisEntityLeftPosX >= anotherEntityLeftPosX && thisEntityRightPosX >= anotherEntityRightPosX)
            || (thisEntityLeftPosX <= anotherEntityLeftPosX && thisEntityRightPosX <= anotherEntityRightPosX)
            || (thisEntityLeftPosX >= anotherEntityLeftPosX && thisEntityRightPosX >= anotherEntityRightPosX)) {
```

Maybe there is an easier way.

Not a duplicate because this is not about a number contained in a set, but a set intersection.

Comment: @Alexander, I don't have a number that want to know if exists in a range. I have 2 ranges and want to know if there is intersection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start thinking in the reverse problem: two intervals, that mathematically can be described as `[amin, amax]` and `[bmin, bmax]`, do not overlap iff `(amin > bmax OR bmin > amax)`.

So, by simple negation of boolean expressions, these intervals overlap if and only if: `(amin <= bmax AND bmin <= amax)`.

Comment: Try running this with [0,1] [0,1] which should return `true`.

Comment: Note this will only work if the pairs are organized as [min, max] where min <= max.

Comment: @Alexander of course, I have a minimum and maximum, and I know which one is which.

Comment: I tested Kyle and ComuSoft solutions, and all worked, but this is the most simple.

Comment: @JorgeeFG That is contradictory to what you said in the comments of CommuSoft's solution.

Comment: @Kyle yes I musunderstood him, I commented again to say it

Answer (score 4):

The following should work, where `a` and `b` are your two ranges.

```
if (aMin <= bMax && aMax >= bMax ||
    bMin <= aMax && bMax >= aMax)
{
    // OVERLAP
}
```

Comment: Yes; that does the trick. Two *in the middle checks* to resolve symmetry.

Comment: There is a simpler way though  :) Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
int left = Math.max(thisEntityLeftPosX,anotherEntityLeftPosX);
int right = Math.min(thisEntityRightPosX,anotherEntityRightPosX);
if(left <= right) {
    //overlap
} else {
    //don't overlap
}
```

[**jDoodle demo with your sample input**](http://jdoodle.com/a/oH)

The idea is that you calculate some sort of intersection: the intersection starts as the last of the given two; and ends as the minimum of the two. There are elements in the intersection if the `left` is thus less than or equal to the `right`.

This program **makes the assumption** that **`thisEntityLeftPosX` is smaller than `thisEntityRightPosX`**. The same holds for the `another...`. In case the assumption doesn't hold. You can modify the code as:

```
int temp;
if(thisEntityLeftPosX > thisEntityRightPosX) {
    temp = thisEntityLeftPosX;
    thisEntityLeftPosX = thisEntityRightPosX;
    thisEntityRightPosX = temp;
}
if(anotherEntityLeftPosX > anotherEntityRightPosX) {
    temp = anotherEntityLeftPosX;
    anotherEntityLeftPosX = anotherEntityRightPosX;
    anotherEntityRightPosX = temp;
}
int left = Math.max(thisEntityLeftPosX,anotherEntityLeftPosX);
int right = Math.min(thisEntityRightPosX,anotherEntityRightPosX);
if(left <= right) {
    //overlap
} else {
    //don't overlap
}
```

A possible extra is that if the ranges intersect, you have immediately constructed the range of the intersection. For `[22;30]` and `[29;33]` this thus generates the new range `[left;right]=[29;33]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try but I can't make the assumption you noted. I don't know the ranges

Comment: @JorgeeFG: but you know that the start of a range is less than or equal to the end of the range. That's what's written there.

Comment: I like this solution. If you can't make the assumption, you can just check `thisEntityLeftPosX > thisEntityRightPosX` and swap them if true. Same for `another..`

Comment: This is a good solution, I would like to select this as answer too. I appreciate the explanation it was very clear.

Comment: @CommuSoft I misunderstood your note before, yes, Left is always smaller than Right.

Answer (score 1):

Just using min/max :

if follwing condition is true - they **don't** intersect

`maxA < minB || maxB < minA`

Comment: Can you please be more explicit, I have ints that represent maximum and minimum, not arrays.

Comment: I don't think the OP uses collections explicitly, only two integers to specify a range.

Comment: Furthermore converting it to a collection is rather inefficient. Imagine a range from `0` to `1e9` and one from `5e8` to `1e9`

Comment: Even though you can easily create collections out min/max, I think I missunderstood your question. There is a better way. Will fix the answer